# Strange for-each loop java

Tags: java, loops, foreach

Could anyone tell me, why does it works?

```
int[] ints = {1,2,3};
for(int i : ints) {
System.out.println(i); i = 0;
}
```

Why can I set 0 as i, but it still iterates?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to set i to 0? Since its pass by value and not reference, i is set to 0, but for ints nothing changes.

Comment: Try printing the value of i at various parts of the code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `i` isn't a control variable in that loop, it's just one of the values in the array. Per [JLS§14.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), for arrays, the enhanced `for` loop is equivalent to this:

> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:
>
> ...
>
> ```
> for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
>     {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
>     Statement
> }
> ```

So applying that to your loop:

```
int[] ints = {1,2,3};
for (int index = 0; index < ints.length; index++) {
    int i = ints[index];
    System.out.println(i);
    i = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`i` is not the loop's index in this case, it's the value of the current element of the array. Therefore changing it doesn't affect the iteration.

It is equivalent to:

```
int[] ints = {1,2,3};
for (int index = 0; index < ints.length; index++) {
    int i = ints[index];
    System.out.println(i);
    i = 0;
}
```

Comment: I suppose it's not *that* surprising we chose the same variable names for the index and length. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I actually didn't choose a variable for length. As for `index`, we couldn't use `i`, could we? :)

Comment: Indeed. :-) (Sorry, eyes are a bit off this morning, somehow saw a length var that wasn't there.)

Answer (score 2):

```
for( int i : ints )
```

is called enhanced for loop . When you deal iterable like this , you deal with element in iterable rather then index .

You can read this

> for each element i { // do this ; }

In your case `i` is not index , it is current element in iterable.

> iterable is not instance of Iterable here . It is in generic sense that any collection that can be iterated using like this.

Comment: `ints` isn't an iterable, it's an array (which is relevant as there are really two enhanced `for` loops, one for iterables, another for arrays).